# nRF Connect Mobile - Setting Security Parameters

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to bond two smartphones via BLE using the nRF Connect Mobile App. Is there any way to change the security parameters for bonding? Unfortunately, there is nearly no documentation for the app, and I didn't find a way to do this. Bonding is just started without any options.

Comment: No, that's defined by the system.

Comment: That's nasty, because some smartphones seem unable to conduct the Passkey Pairing. I just can't enter the passkey, so I hoped that I could at least make it work with Just Works pairing...